# Radio button checked changed event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons on a simple web page and If I click one of them the other should be false(i.e checked=false) but it's not working Can anyone point me the mistake I'm doing.I knew it's a silly one but I need to know what's going on?

Here are the radio buttons:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="Rb1" runat="server" Text=""/>

<asp:RadioButton ID="Rb2" runat="server" Text=""/>
```

Onchecked changed event:

```
Protected Sub Rb1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Rb1.CheckedChanged
    Rb2.Checked = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Rb2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Rb2.CheckedChanged
    Rb1.Checked = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `GroupName` property and [AutoPostBack=True](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx).