# asp.net - RadioButton "CheckedChanged" event does not work when it is unchecked

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I have two RadioButtons on my Web Form and here is the code:

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

When I check RadioButton2, time appears on the page but when I check RadioButton1(RadioButton2 is unchecked now) it does not update the shown time and removes it.

the event function must be called when it checks and unchecks.I don't understand what is wrong here and why the time disappears

(As it is obvious, I know about `GroupName` property and `AutoPostBack`. My problem is something else)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio button checked changed event in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859959/radio-button-checked-changed-event-in-asp-net)

Comment: no. I knew about that

Answer (score 0):

You can check property of each control and check  AutoPostBack=True
and also if checked="true"

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on different ways and opened my pages with different browsers and I figured out a few things. the most important of them which is related to my problem:

- When a control Calls back, the page refreshes and that is why the time disappears. It sends the status of all controls using `post` method to itself and they would be the same way as they were. But the time is not written on a control and it would not be saved.
  As I said if it was for example on a `Label`, the text would be kept:

`Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();`

It answers the first question but I still think that the event function must be called when the `RadioButton` is being unchecked.